# Sort file by key with awk or perl like a join without presorting

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk

I want to join two tab separated files, but they are in a different order. I know that it is doable with awk, but I don't know how. Here is the equivalent toy python code (python is too memory inefficient for this task without crazy workarounds):

```
import pandas as pd
from random import shuffle

a = ['bar','qux','baz','foo','spam']
df = pd.DataFrame({'nam':a,'asc':[1,2,3,4,5],'desc':[5,4,3,2,1]})

shuffle(a)
print(a)

dex = pd.DataFrame({'dex' : a})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'VAL1' :[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]})

pd.merge(dex, df,left_on='dex',right_on='nam')[['asc','desc','nam']]
```

I have two files:
For file one, column 2 holds the identifier for each row, there 5 columns I don't need, and then there are about 3 million columns of data.

For file two, There are 12 columns, with the second column containing the same identifiers in a different order, along with additional ids.

I want to sort file one to have the same identifiers and order as file two, with the other columns appropriately rearranged.

File one is potentially multiple gigabytes.

Is this easier with awk and/or other GNU tools, or should I use perl?

Comment: @ikegami I  do mention that file one has millions of columns. I just realized that I don't actually have to reorganise file one, which would be the hard operation, so I can in fact do this in python, so I'm going to edit the question for my future use.

Comment: Put your data in SQLite, use the appropriate `JOIN`.

Comment: Re "*I do mention that file one has millions of columns.*", That's interesting, but not enough. Your edit probably provides enough information, though. If the file is in the order of GB, and you have 3 million columns of data, you have a very small number of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the size of `file1` is in the order of GB, and you have 3 million columns of data, you have a tiny number of lines (no more than 200). While you can't load all of the lines themselves into memory, you could easily load all of their *locations*.

```
use feature qw( say );

use Fcntl qw( SEEK_SET );

open(my $fh1, '<', $qfn1) or die("Can't open \"$qfn1\": $!\n");
open(my $fh2, '<', $qfn2) or die("Can't open \"$qfn2\": $!\n");

my %offsets;
while (1) {
   my $offset = tell($fh1);
   my $row1 = <$fh1>;
   last if !defined($row1);

   chomp($row1);
   my @fields1 = split(/\t/, $row1);
   my $key = $fields1[1];
   $offsets{$key} = $offset;
}

while (my $row2 = <$fh2>) {
   chomp($row2);
   my @fields2 = split(/\t/, $row2);
   my $key = $fields2[1];
   my $offset = $offsets{$key};
   if (!defined($offset)) {
      warn("Key $key not found.\n");
      next;
   }

   seek($fh1, $offset, SEEK_SET);
   my $row1 = <$fh1>;
   chomp($row1);
   my @fields1 = split(/\t/, $row1);

   say join "\t", @fields2, @fields1[6..$#fields1];
}
```

This approach can be taken in Python as well.

Note: There exists a much simpler solution if the order is more flexible (i.e. if you're ok with the output being ordered as the records are ordered in `file1`). This assuming `file2` easily fits in memory.

Answer (score 2):

3 million columns of data, eh?  It sounds like you're doing some NLP work.

Assuming this is true, and your matrix is sparse, python can handle it just fine (just not with `pandas`).  Look at `scipy.sparse`.  Example:

```
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix

A = dok_matrix((10,10))
A[1,1] = 1

B = dok_matrix((10,10))
B[2,2] = 2

print A+B
```

DOK stands for "dictionary of keys", which is typically used to build the sparse matrix, then it's usually converted to CSR, etc. depending on use.  See [available sparse matrix types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

Comment: Amazing answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is [not to split](https://www.nu42.com/2013/02/splitting-long-lines-is-slow.html) any more than necessary. If you have enough memory, putting the smaller file in a hash, and then reading through the second file ought to work.

Consider the following example (note the run time of this script includes the time it takes to create sample data):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# This is a string containing 10 lines corresponding to your "file one"
# Second column has the record ID
# Normally, you'd be reading this from a file

my $big_file = join "\n",
    map join("\t", 'x', $_, ('x') x 3_000_000),
    1 .. 10
;

# This is a string containing 10 lines corresponding to your "file two"
# Second column has the record ID

my $small_file = join "\n",
    map join("\t", 'y', $_, ('y') x 10),
    1 .. 10
;

# You would normally pass file names as arguments

join_with_big_file(
    \$small_file,
    \$big_file,
);

sub join_with_big_file {
    my $small_records = load_small_file(shift);
    my $big_file = shift;

    open my $fh, '<', $big_file
        or die "Cannot open '$big_file': $!";

    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        my ($first, $id, $rest) = split /\t/, $line, 3;
        print join("\t", $first, $id, $rest, $small_records->{$id}), "\n";
    }

    return;
}

sub load_small_file {
    my $file = shift;
    my %records;

    open my $fh, '<', $file
        or die "Cannot open '$file' for reading: $!";

    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        # limit the split
        my ($first, $id, $rest) = split /\t/, $line, 3;
        # I drop the id field here so it is not duplicated in the joined
        # file. If that is not a problem, $records{$id} = $line
        # would be better.
        $records{$id} = join("\t", $first, $rest);
    }

    return \%records;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't output the line in the desired order (the order they are found in `file2`).

Comment: @ikegami Ah, I had missed that. I might be have time to fix this in a few hours.